# "Blocking" method to make code cache friendly

Tags: c, caching, optimization

Hey so I'm looking at a matrix shift code, and need to make it cache friendly (fewest cache misses possible). The code looks like this:

```
int i, j, temp;
for(i=1;, i< M; i++){
    for(j=0; j< N; j++){
        temp = A[i][j];
        A[i][j] = A[i-1][j];
        A[i-1]][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Assume M and N are parameters of the function, noting M to number of rows, and N to number of columns. Now to make this more cache friendly, the book gives out two problems for optimization. When the matrix is 4x4, s=1, E=2, b=3 , and when the matrix is 128x128, s=5, E=2, b=3. 
**(s = # of set index bits (S = s^2 is the number of sets, E = number of lines per set, and b = # of block bits (so B = b^2 is block size))**

So using the blocking method, I should access the matrix by block size, to avoid getting a miss, and the cache having to fetch the information from the cache a level higher. So here is what I assume:

Block size is 9 bytes for each

With the 4x4 matrix, the number of elements that fit evenly on a block is:
**blocksize*(number of columns/blocksize)** = 9*(4/9) = 4
So if each row will fit on one block, why is it not cache friendly?

With the 128x128 matrix, with the same logic as above, each block will hold (9*(128/9)) = 128.

**So obviously after calculating that, this equation is wrong. I'm looking at the code from this page http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/waside/waside-blocking.pdf**

Once I reached this point, I knew I was lost, which is where you guys come in! Is it as simple as saying each block holds 9 bytes, and 8 bytes (two integers) are what fits evenly into it? Sorry this stuff really confuses me, I know I'm all over the place. Just to be clear, these are my concerns:

**How do you know how many elements will fit in a block?
Do the number of lines or sets affect this number? If so, how?
Any in depth explanation of the code posted on the linked page.**

Really just trying to get a grasp of this.

**UPDATE:
Okay so here is where I'm at for the 4x4 matrix.**

I can read 8 bytes at a time, which is 2 integers. The original function will have cache misses because C loads into row-major order, so every time it wants A[i-1][j] it will miss, and load the block that holds A[i-1][j] which would either be A[i-1][0] and A[i-1][1] or A[i-1][2] and A[i-1][3].

So, would the best way to go about this be to create another temp variable, and do A[i][0] = temp, A[i][1] = temp2, then load A[i-1][0] A[i-1][1] and set them to temp, and temp2 and just set the loop to j<2? For this question, it is specifically for the matrices described; I understand this wouldn't work on all sizes.

Comment: `(9*(128/9)) = 128`? Not for integer divide it isn't.

Comment: Question - is this just for your own knowledge, or are you trying to implement this in some massive number cruncher?  Notice that the article said that the block doesn't break even until after an array size of 100 - that's a pretty big matrix.  They also said that modern processors don't benefit (probably because they can use modern op-codes that multiple many values at the same time - SIMD stuff.)

Comment: If `b` is a bit count, then `B = 2^b`, which means `B = 8` when `b = 3`.

Comment: Yeah B = 2^b makes way more sense. But I'm still confused if that means each block holds two integers? And do the number of sets, or lines play into this anywhere?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan no haha I have a lab coming up where I'm going to have to do something similar to this so I'm using the book for now.

Comment: Look up "Cache Lines" when you get a chance.  This should enlighten you on what fits into a block.  The first Google hit explains it quite nicely.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan yup haha already read that! It actually confused me more because on many of the articles and what not I found say that cache lines are the same as cache blocks. So if there is 1 set, with 2 lines, and a block size of 8 bytes, do these two lines each hold 8 bytes of data, resulting in 16 bytes total, wouldn't the original function get a miss, hit, hit, hit on the 4x4 matrix on each row?

Comment: Let's pretend that our cache lines are 32 bytes (not uncommon).  Let's pretend that integers are 4-bytes as we are in 32-bit land.  Then, 8 integers can fit into a single cache lines, providing that the entire structure is aligned to the same size as the cache lines.  (32 / 4 == 8)  So, if we can work with just those 8 integers and hit all permutations of their multiplies, we've saved a lot of cache loading time.  That is the gist of the article.  Of course in the real world, there are threads and OS switches and other fun that gets in the way...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I understand that, I'm just having a hard time implementing that knowledge into this problem. So I can read 8 bytes at a time (two integers), right? And C is row-major ordered so a[0][0] and a[0][1] will be in the same block/line, a[0][2] and a[0][3] will be, a[1][0] and a[1][1], etc.? Then a lot of the misses will be coming from loading a[-][1] and a[-][2] at the same time?

Comment: I added an update with how I'm looking this, can anyone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: re: update: 4x4... *so every time it wants `A[i-1][j]` it will miss".  That's not how caches work.  Accesses don't have to be sequential to hit in cache, just near enough to other accesses.  Since the whole 4x4 matrix of 4B `int`s fits in one 64B cache line on a modern x86 CPU, you should expect at most one cache miss per matrix, and be optimizing to help the compiler move memory in bigger blocks (with vector instructions).  See also [my answer this extremely similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37063701/224132).  Are you taking the same class?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was to think of the matrix in column major order rather than row major order.

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone in the future. Thanks to @Michael Dorgan for getting me thinking.

End results for 128x128 matrix:
Original: 16218 misses
Optimized: 8196 misses